# passing array as key pair in json format to function pgsql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have created a function that accepts a json. Here is the query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.data_get(
    data json)
    RETURNS SETOF json 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000

AS $BODY$
DECLARE
        declare _text text;
        
    BEGIN
    -- get fields data from json - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html
    _text = data::json#>>'{text}';
```

and this is how i call this function

```
select * from data_get ('{"text":"my"}'::json) as info;
```

and this works fine

now i want to pass the array element so i added the variables like this

```
DECLARE
        declare 
           _text text;
           _ids bigint[];
```

and accessed from json like this

```
_ids = data::json#>>'{ids}';
```

but when i call this function

```
select * from data_get ('{"text":"","ids":[1]}'::json) as info;
```

it shows

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[1]"
DETAIL:  Missing "=" after array dimensions.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function posts_get(json) line 18 at assignment
SQL state: 22P02
```

how can i call this function?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres doesn't do implicit conversion from json array to postgres array.

You need to use own function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.json_to_int_array(json)
 RETURNS integer[]
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT array_agg(v::int) FROM json_array_elements_text($1) g(v)
$function$

postgres=# SELECT public.json_to_int_array(('{"text":"","ids":[1, 2, 3]}'::json)->'ids');
┌───────────────────┐
│ json_to_int_array │
╞═══════════════════╡
│ {1,2,3}           │
└───────────────────┘
(1 row)
```